# how to disable the browser to give warning in php?

Tags: php

When some thing is divided by 0, the webpage will appear a line of waring like this" Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXXX.php on line 109". How can I solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Even the smartest people on this planet haven't been able to solve this problem so far

Answer (score 5):

You find the bug, then you fix it.

You don't suppress errors.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you don't divide by zero.

```
if( $divisor != 0 ) {
    $result = $number / $divisor;
}
else {
    $result = 0; // or print an error or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use error_reporting functions....

```
   <?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all, you have to avoid these errors, using conditions or exceptions
if it's not possible you can disable error reporting

```
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
```

source - [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)